# ROUNDUP SUM values in a column in Google Sheets' query

Tags: google-sheets, rounding, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to `ROUNDUP` the sum values in a column in my google sheets `QUERY`.  I discovered adding `format sum(Col2) '#'` will do the trick *as long as* the sum is `>.5`.  So how do I accomplish the same result if the value is `<.5`?

Here is my formula:

```excel
=QUERY(QUERY(Data!A3:D, "SELECT A,sum(B),C,D where A is not null GROUP BY A,C,D format sum(B) '#'", 0),"OFFSET 1",0)
```

Currently, if the result is `<.5`, it will just display a blank space.

Here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2pkjc8w9Ty12Lpuwyljx0K-afsja6XShUCKB7YJm98/edit#gid=517237313&range=A2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only possible way would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(ROUNDUP(
 QUERY(QUERY(Data!A3:D, 
 "SELECT A,sum(B),C,D where A is not null GROUP BY A,C,D", 0),"OFFSET 1",0)), 
 QUERY(QUERY(Data!A3:D, 
 "SELECT A,sum(B),C,D where A is not null GROUP BY A,C,D", 0),"OFFSET 1",0)))
```

[image: 0]